# Metro StAX implementation - how to configure?

Tags: web-services, java-metro-framework, stax

Is there any way to tell metro what StAX implementation it should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. We need to set system properties:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
```

for example:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory" ,"com.sun.xml.stream.events.ZephyrEventFactory");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory" ,"com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory" ,"com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrWriterFactory");
```

for more information look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbfi.html#bnbfk)